# Adding dynamic filter in module_invoke()

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have created a node named "weekday," and one named "place" on Drupal 7. Next, I created a block view of the fields in "weekday" I wanted to show in the "place" node template.

I implemented it using the following code:

```
$weekday = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'weekday-block');
print render($weekday);
```

Now I would love to add a flexible filter that allows to load the block module with a extra filter of the different weekdays. Weekdays are a taxonomy term field in the node type "weekday".
The reason is that I would like to request the block by jquery in a link like http://www.example.com/place#Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [views_embed_view()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.module/function/views_embed_view/7), rather than module_invoke(), for this so you can pass the 'weekday' term as an argument to the view, such as in the following code:

```
print views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id, $argument);
```

There might be an easier way to do this in Drupal 7/Views by using contextual filters directly from the view itself; I'm not sure how you are planning on using jQuery to load each of these new blocks. Are you doing a load operation with the URL on each one? Is there any reason you need to use the # anchor attribute rather than a URL argument like http://www.example.com/place/Monday?

That could make it easier to set this up within views.

Comment: Hi Kiamlaluno,
Very useful advices.

And you are correct I can use a page/url like you say and get it with ajax instead.
I'm still not sure how to use the argument I parse in my view to filter the results.

Comment: Sure - do you have a contextual filter setup right now? In the 'advanced' section of your view you should add a contextual filter for taxonomy term that will accept an argument from the url as a filter for your view results.

Comment: Please check updated question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24055/d7-embed-view-with-2-contextual-filters-user-id-and-taxanormy-term