# Embed a view with 2 contextual filters (user id and taxonomy term)

Tags: 7, views

I am working on a filtered block view, where I would like to set an extra argument from the template.

Right now I have a page with a URL like this: http://www.page.com/place/test

"test" is a node(nodetype1), and I already use a contextual filter to get the user id form "test" to filter only nodes (of type "nodetype2") by the user of the node "test" to my view block.

Now I would like to filter the view block even more by a taxonomy term in the contenttype2. Problem is that the taxonomy term is not in the URL!

I use:

```
views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id, $argument);
```

But I cant use a URL like: http://www.page.com/term/contenttype2 because I lose the "test" pagename to get user id from.

How can I use both filters at once?

Comment: It is very hard to understand how you have set up your view. Could you provide a more comprehensive listing of the definition including all fields, filters the path and contextual filters for the definition?

Comment: is the desired end result to have a page displaying a nodetype1 with a block on that page displaying a list of nodetype2s owned by the same user filtered by ANY taxonomy term or a certain admin-specified term?

Comment: Jimajamma > Yes, by a certain term. But a term set dynamically from the template file and not directly as a filter in the view.